# how to get selected cell value in gridview using asp..net

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I am using a `Link` button in a `GridView`. I need the value of the button I have clicked. Is there any way to achieve this ?

Comment: Do you have this LinkButton in a TemplateField?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want to get related row from GridView

```
protected void GridView1_SelectedIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewSelectEventArgs e)
{
    GridViewRow row = GridView1.Rows[e.NewSelectedIndex];


}
```

The required cell you can get from cells collection row.Cells